# Missing comments on "thawing ice" question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments

[What spells can be used to thaw or melt ice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132627/what-spells-can-be-used-to-thaw-or-melt-ice)

My question has some comments asking for clarification that I haven't addressed, but they magically vanished just as I tried to reply to them!

I don't think all of them are chatty or unnecessary, but why they got removed?
Can I have some of them unaddressed clarification-comment go back?

(I don't remember which ones and what they are asking for, unfortunately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I undeleted a couple comments for you to edit clarifications into your question.